# Accepting nominations — Who should moderate this site?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Ideally Moderators are elected by the community, but until the community is large enough to hold a proper election, we will be appointing three provisional Moderators to fill those roles.

We need your help. Please nominate folks you would like to see become provisional moderators for this site. Your input will provide valuable insight to help us make our selections. You can read more about the process here: **[Moderators Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).**

### The Nomination Process:

- **Nominate a user** by posting an 'answer' below. Each nomination should be a separate answer. Use the template at the bottom of this post to complete your nomination.
- **Self nominations are encouraged.** This is a volunteer activity, so users should not feel obligated to accept these positions. A self-nomination is simply a way to say, "I am very much interested in this, so let my record speak for itself."
- **Tell us about the candidates.** Nominations can include links to other activities like Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, or any relevant thoughts/links that may help us make an informed decision.
- **The nominee should indicate their acceptance** by editing the answer to say they accept/decline the nomination. Optionally, nominees are encouraged to write a bit about themselves following their acceptance.

  > I accept/decline this nomination.
  >
  > Hi, I am name/location/fun fact (all optional). I live in <location>, so I am generally active on this site from <time> to <time>. Some other things you may want to know about me are…

### Here is what we'll be looking for in a Moderator candidate:

We are looking for members who are deeply engaged in the community's development; members who:

- Have been consistently active during the earliest weeks of this site's creation
- Show an interest in their meta's community-building activities
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [**A Theory of Moderation**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

---

### Nomination Template

To nominate a candidate, copy and paste the text below as an answer and complete your nomination writeup:

> <a href="http://crafts.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="http://crafts.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   <a href="http://meta.crafts.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="http://meta.crafts.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   ###Notes:
>   This nominee would be a good choice because …

[image]

Comment: Can I nominate more than one? (Each in their own answer if course!)

Comment: @Erica I don't see why not. You would just be bringing the options to light. The community would help decide.

Comment: @Erica Certainly, there is no problem nominating more than one user.

Comment: I like the list, looks like a good crew.

Comment: What is our timeline for this? In the next couple months? Longer, shorter?

Comment: @CreationEdge The initial selection process is slated to start going into next week.

Answer (score 13):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

This nominee would be a good choice because she's already been making positive contributions to both the "front" and "back" ends of Arts & Crafts. My experience with her contributions to other SEs (specifically Seasoned Advice) is that she's polite, considerate, well-versed with how a StackExchange site works, gives thorough and thoughtful answers, and contributes on both topic and meta sides. She'd be an excellent moderator.

---

I accept this nomination.

Hi, I am Catherine (Catija). I live in Austin, TX, so I am generally available to be active on this site from 15:00 Z to 3:00 Z. Some other things you may want to know about me are that my preferred crafting projects tend to be crochet, and I don't knit at all. I have experience with cross stitching, painting, and jewelry making to a small degree but I'm happy to learn about all sorts of things. Additionally, I love to cook and read and I have a bachelor's degree in film making.

My most active sites are Movies and TV and Cooking and I'm a regular chat participant on several sites. I also really love to learn about how the SE system works, and I spend tons of time on Meta.SE posting questions and answers and trying to convince the powers that be that these sites still need improving.

I know that I've made some very specific statements on Meta about how I think this site should be run and what subjects I think should be on and off topic - and as a user, I am allowed to have those opinions - but I want you all to know that I respect this site as a *community* of users. If we as a community decide to take a site in a direction other than my preferred direction, I will accept this decision and, if selected as a moderator, will work to align the site with that decision.

I would be tickled to have the opportunity to stand as one of the pro-tem mods to move this site through the path to  full-site status.

Comment: +1 to this, I'm 100% ok with this!

Comment: +1 on this nomination!  Catija is a valued contributor to Movies and TV.  She is always willing to assist using her vast knowledge of any given subject.  She is an active participant on the main site as well as chat.  She would be an excellent moderator on any SE site!

Answer (score 12):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

This nominee would be a good choice because he's interested in helping Arts & Crafts to be a healthy beta!

I've been excited about the prospect of an Art & Crafts stack since I heard about the Area 51 proposal. I'm a chronically aspiring artist, with a focus on figure drawing, although I try to dabble in anything that allows me to create.

Since the private beta has launched, I've been an active user on both Q&A and meta. I regularly check the review queue and also try to leave guiding comments for users that need to improve their posts. I've been involved with some tagging discussions, as I know from experience that early tagging issues can cause big problems later.

As a moderator *pro tem*, I would continue engaging in activities that help keep the site healthy. I would help keep the stack on track with policies as the community develops them. I spend as much time on Meta as I do Q&A, even on SFF (my most active stack).

Regardless, I will continue to contribute to the stack in any form I can. When my artistic knowledge fails, I'll work to improve the site with the editing and moderation privileges I've earned.

---

I'm in GMT - 5 (US Central), and I'll be primarily available from 22:00-04:00 GMT M-F, pretty much all day on weekends, and a smattering of times throughout the day (especially if I receive my mobile notifications.)

<sub>This message has been paid for and approved by CreationEdge.</sub>

Comment: +1 to this, you've been awesome in getting this site started!

Comment: +1 to this nomination!  CreationEdge has always displayed a friendly and outgoing demeanor in SFF chat.  He has proven to be knowledgeable on the workings of SE as well as being a talented artist.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

This nominee would be a good choice because she's got moderator experience and she likes Arts & Crafts.

---

I'm Erica. I live in the eastern US, and am active between ~11am and ~1am UTC.

I have been [a *pro tem* moderator at Parenting.SE](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/users/4054/erica) for a bit over a year, so I know about the Theory of Moderation and how the tools work. I strive to keep things civil and balanced on a site that's more subjective than average, and make an effort to constructively encourage users as much as possible.

I'm a fan of community moderation, following voting and meta guidance, and I am pleased to see we have so many engaged users already on the necessary reputation for that. Organized tags and an active meta are also important parts of a good StackExchange site, and I'm looking forward to working on them (whether as a moderator or not).

As for arts/crafts, I have some experience in sewing, knitting, cross stitch, decoupage, upcycling, polymer clay sculpture, and whatever my kids feel like making a mess with (we're currently working on an Anne Boleyn costume for a school presentation!) -- But the biggest challenge I have in crafting is *finding time*. I readily admit that I don't have a whole lot of reputation yet on A&C. I'm still feeling inexpert, since I'm just a dabbler in all sorts of miscellaneous things.

Comment: If I'd known that you were interested in taking on another site I would have nominated you! Glad to see your hat in the ring. :)

Comment: @Catija Thanks! It took a bit of thought to decide, but I've got the time and inclination so why not :)

Comment: I was waiting for your nomination. You would have got more votes had you nominated some days back. Happy to see you.

Comment: Erica's moderation on Parenting has been exceptional, even in the face of some rather obnoxious users.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

This nominee would be a good choice because a pile of bagels is delicious. Oh, uh, seriously though... Matt is one of the top contributors of Questions and Answers so far the private beta, indicating a strong level of interest that is fundamental to being a reliable and often-present moderator. He's also active in Meta and helping maintain quality tags, both important to a nicely organized site.

---

I would like to accept this nomination

Name is Matt which should come as a big surprise. I live in Ottawa, Ontario and am online throughout the day, on various SE sites like StackOverflow and Woodworking, checking in to see what is going on and contributing when I can. I have always considered myself crafty and been looking forward to this site starting up.

**Bit about myself**

My crafting experience is with woodworking, crocheting, origami (mostly modular), sewing by hand and drawing. I love all kinds of crafting and will generally try anything for fun. For example: In the past I have bound my own books, done some acrylic painting with my wife, cut glass for frames and whatever strikes my fancy. I am also a fan of upcycling. I love garage sales and finding interesting ways to reuse things. I also have kids so repairing toys comes up (that's where my sewing experience comes from) and many outside the box ideas come as a result (Daughter tore elephants out of here pop up book and lost some of the parts.... still fixed it though).

**What I can do for this site**

I have been an active SE member for more than 2 years now. I have been a very active member of Woodworking.SE. I have been involved in that site since its commitment and a key member since it started in private beta back in March of 2015. I understand some of the things that are needed to both get and keep a beta going.

As a mod I would strive to keep the quality of the site high and do what I can to encourage new members and crafting scopes to help make this site succeed.  There is still a lot to learn when it comes to these things so while I might not have the right idea at first I will uphold the communities decisions when it comes to new directions.

---

Regardless, just like [CreationEdge](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/a/159/44), I am going to be here to help anyway with new questions, activity on chat, and as a useful Meta presence. I want this site to do well.

Comment: +1 I would have nominated you as well!

Answer (score 4):

Late nomination here:

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

This nominee would be a good choice because he's enthusiastic about Arts & Crafts and he has experience as a moderator.

---

I haven't been on this site very long (I joined on the first day of public beta), but I really like the idea of an Arts & Crafts SE and intend to participate here a lot more and help to build this community, regardless of who the pro tem mods are. Although I haven't had time for much practical arts & crafts activity in the last few years, I have past experience with drawing, sewing, knitting, origami, and making various small dolls and paper models. With all of this and a good deal of [Google-fu](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/19973/87724), I feel I can make a decent contribution to this community in terms of Q&A.

In the short time I've been a member here, I've already contributed several answers and questions on the main site, and also a few posts on meta which I hope will help towards some policy-making for A&C. (In fact, [apparently](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=participation) I'm now one of the most active users of meta.) I've also been active in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38932/the-studio), which is a good place for community building.

Perhaps most importantly, I'm already a moderator on another site ([Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/)), where my motto is to treat everyone fairly, to engage constantly with the community, and always to be ready to receive feedback and act upon it. I can almost always see both points of view in a dispute, which is helpful in mediating, and I prefer a gentle approach to moderation where possible. I also have a lot of experience of SE as a whole, and am familiar with main meta and overarching SE policies.

[http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/4859979.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/4859979)

**In summary:** I have less rep and activity (*so far* - watch this space!) than the other nominees here, but I already have moderator experience, which would be a useful thing to have in a pro-tem mod team. If chosen, initially at least I would probably take a back seat to the more experienced A&Cers in policy-making decisions, but would be able to advise and help with more general moderation issues.

I live in the UK, so my activity times complement those of most of the other nominees here.

Comment: +1 to this!  Rand al'Thor has always been a knowledge and helpful user.  His knowledge on the workings of SE is very impressive.  He is an extremely fair and just moderator on SFF as well as being very friendly and helpful in all matters.  He really seems to care about SE and would definitely help be a part of assisting any site to flourish.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

[image]

Okay, I'll self-nominate.

#### Main

I was around a lot during the early days of the site's life, and I tried to answer what I could. I also asked a question and was going to ask more, but other people got there before I did. Going forward my activity is going to be pretty similar: answering what I can (which, admittedly, isn't masses, but I know enough).

#### Meta

I like meta. Meta is where the community is shaped, brought together, and defined. Again, I've answered what I can here, and I'd like to be able to help the site grow and flourish.

#### Rep

This shouldn't matter overly much, but it's probably worth a mention: my rep isn't that high, because I haven't answered masses of questions. I prefer to lurk and answer what I can well, rather than just trying to answer everything to boost my rep.

#### Why me?

Because:

- I'm interested
- I'm dedicated
- I've got [a moderator](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/8) as a brother (okay, that doesn't count for *much*, but it would give me easy access to guidance for tricky situations)
- I'm calm, level-headed, and I think I can do a good job.

I'm in the UK, so UTC or UTC+1 time, which seems to provide a fairly good spread.

Comment: Only if you change your username to CraftOfCode!! ;-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor don't spoil my April Fools' joke now :P

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

inskista would be an awesome moderator because they were one of the earliest members of the site, have contributed a ton (there are two contributions from them on the front page) and they are really helpful/detailed with their answers and edits.

Comment: Has inkista responded to indicate whether they accept this nomination?

Comment: @Randal'Thor, they haven't.