# Please welcome your moderators pro tempore!

Tags: discussion, moderation

First off, thanks to everyone who participated at the [moderator nomination](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153/accepting-nominations-who-should-moderate-this-site) meta post!

I may eventually be contacting additional users to fill more moderator slots, but I wanted to get the folks below activated before things really started to take off.

Throughout the beta, we need members from this site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us ensure that this community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: CreationEdge]
[image: Erica]
[image: Catija]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Yes, almost certainly. There are many members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition who are not moderators. My inability to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections several weeks after graduation.**

Most of all, please be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: Congrats all around. I know we will be fine with these folks helping out.

Comment: Congratulations to all three of you.

Comment: Congratulations! Really excited to see where this community will go!

Comment: Thanks -- it's an honor and a privilege, and I'm looking forward to helping move things towards graduation :)

Answer (score 8):

### Congratulations!

Catija, CreationEdge, and Erica (in alphabetical order) are all great choices, and I have no doubt they'll do an excellent job of moderating this site which they clearly care about a lot. I look forward to watching the community here grow and thrive with them at its helm.

<sub>To Catija and CreationEdge: congrats on your very first diamonds! See you in TL ;-)</sub>